# Apache Wicket Panel's TextFields dont refresh after closing the Modal Window

Tags: apache, model-view-controller, wicket, wicket-6

I have a use case where a modal dialog has three set of Addresses of checkbox (Address A, Address B, Other Address) divided in separate divs for each address type for the user to select one address.

Each address type has their own set of TextFields for showing Name, House no, Street, City, Postal code and country.

So far so good. I was able to handle the selection of Address and pass the textfield values to the model. The model is getting reflected with the selected address.

On click of the "OK" button of Modal Window, (AjaxLink), there is a sub-panel (under another main panel, having all the address readonly textfields in it) which has to display the selected address type. But it isnt getting refresh. But the textfields model is having the updated values. (I have found this during debug)

Have tried everything on this site:
- using LoadableDetachableModel, setDefaultModel(), creating new instance of the Panel etc. but nothing is of use

i have also pasted the relevant code parts here. Request anyone who can guide me here as to what is going wrong and where I need to correct to get the sub-panel text fields refreshed on click of "OK' button of the modal.

thanks in  advance

```
--ShipmentAddressSelectedPanel constructor Code
  public ShipmentAddressSelectedPanel(String id, IModel<OrderDTO> orderDTOIModel) {
    super(id, orderDTOIModel);
    name = orderDTOIModel.getObject().getDeliveryAddress().getName();
    streetAddress = subOrderDTOIModel.getObject().getDeliveryAddress().getStreet();
    floor = orderDTOIModel.getObject().getDeliveryAddress().getFloor();
    postalNumber = orderDTOIModel.getObject().getDeliveryAddress().getZipCode();
    city = orderDTOIModel.getObject().getDeliveryAddress().getCity();
    add(new TextField<>("name", new LoadableDetachableModel<String>() {
        @Override
        protected String load() {
            return "" + name;
        }
    }));
    add(new TextField<>("streetAddress", new LoadableDetachableModel<String>() {
        @Override
        protected String load() {
            return "" + streetAddress;
        }
    }));
    add(new TextField<>("floor", new LoadableDetachableModel<String>() {
        @Override
        protected String load() {
            return "" + floor;
        }
    }));
    //floor
    add(new TextField<>("postalNumber", new LoadableDetachableModel<String>() {
        @Override
        protected String load() {
            return "" + postalNumber;
        }
    }));
    //postalNumber
    add(new TextField<>("city", new LoadableDetachableModel<String>() {
        @Override
        protected String load() {
            return "" + city;
        }
    }));

}

--code of onClick of AjaxLink ("Ok") button
add(new AjaxLink("saveAddress") {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            if (addressA.getValue().equals("true"))
            {
                onSaveAddress(target, getShipmentAddressModelFromDeliveryAddress(addressAModel.getObject()));
            }

--Code of onSaveAddress where the logic refresh Panel is called from the main panel
@Override
public void onSaveAddress(AjaxRequestTarget target, ShipmentAddressModel shipmentAddressModel) {

                    ShipmentAddressSelectedPanel newShipmentAddressSelectedPanel = new ShipmentAddressSelectedPanel("showShipmentAddressSelected", orderDTOIModel);
                    newShipmentAddressSelectedPanel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
                    //newShipmentAddressSelectedPanel.setDefaultModelObject(orderDTOIModel);
                    target.add(newShipmentAddressSelectedPanel);
                    showAddressModal.close(target);
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a new ShipmentAddressSelectedPanel, but it doesn't get added to the component tree.
Note that AjaxRequestTarget skips components, which are not inside the current page. You should have a log entry:

```
"Component .. with markupid: .. not rendered because it was already removed from page"
```

Note your usage of LDM is wrong, it should be:

```
//name = orderDTOIModel.getObject().getDeliveryAddress().getName();
add(new TextField<>("name", new LoadableDetachableModel<String>() {
    @Override
    protected String load() {
        return orderDTOIModel.getObject().getDeliveryAddress().getName();
    }
}));
```

Otherwise you'll pull out the name once only and never update when the model has changed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. actually I tried to re-use the existing ShipmentAddressSelectedPanel ref. even that didnt helped & in one of d posts in SOF i gone through a post mentioning that we can create a new panel for refreshing the model values. So that was the reason to put that. Can you please advice what I have to do here if I should not create a new ShipmentAddressSelectedPanel? about LDM, I will checkout the way you adviced and let you know? thanks once again!

Comment: Hi @svenmeier, your LDM suggested change worked.. thanks a ton! thank you very much.